# Webscrape final step to take elements to pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

Im runing a webscrape and have run into trouble in the last process of converting the text/link into a pd table to export to excel. I have two columns: title and seek (link) and i have used the following code:

```
df = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
     title = link.get('title')
     seek = link.get('href')
     df.append(title)
     df.append(seek)

print(df)
```

The df then returns output as below which is all in one line:

```
'title text' , 'seek link', 'title text', 'seek link', 'title text' , 'seek link' etc etc
```

What would my next line of code be to create a pandas dataframe with the columns "title" and then "seek" link? So that it looks like:

```
Col 1 = title        |      Col 2 =seek
title text           |      seek link
title text           |      seek link
title text           |      seek link
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Save title and seek, independently and then make dataframe.

```
Title_list = []
Seek_list = []

for link in soup.find_all('a'):
     title = link.get('title')
     seek = link.get('href')
     Title_list.append(title)
     Seek_list.append(seek)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Title":Title_list, "Seek":Seek_list})
```